# Windows 8.1 decides to randomly change locale in programs

Tags: windows-8, language

I've recently upgraded to 8.1 and I'm experiencing some rather annoying problems regarding the UI language. Once every now and then it decides to change it from English to Bulgarian. All of my language settings at the control panel are set to English. Unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem. This is quite annoying because I open Windows Explorer and it's in English. I close it, and 10 minutes later, it's in Bulgarian or even worse - half English, half Bulgarian. I'm out of ideas what may be causing this issue.

I have installed MS Office 2010 with bulgarian proofing tools, which by default install bulgarian language pack for MS Office, but I've configure the UI settings to use only English. Therefore I'm not confident this is the cause of the issue.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Is removing the language packs you don't want to use an option?

Comment: Hmm.. It appears Windows has decided to automatically install the Bulgarian display language pack. Probably when I did full windows update after doing the fresh install. I'll give it a day to see if the problem still exists. If not, I'll ask you to post this as an answer. :)

Comment: Its not really worthy of being posted as an answer.